# Eidolon Stat Block Error Checking

Tags: pathfinder-1e, eidolon

Okay this may or may not be the site for asking this but i was wondering if anyone could see if i messed up anywhere before i add it to a proper sheet, pretty sure my math is right and i didn't miss anything but this is my first Eidolon and i only have one sheet.

Level 10 half-Elf Naturalist Summoner's Eidolon
Eidolon, Tora (The Bouncer)
HD 8d10
Base Form: Biped, Humanoid Tiger (Gray With Black Stripes).
Size: Medium.
Speed: 30 ft.
AC 21 (34 with barkskin, mage armor and shield)=10+5 dex+4 natural armor+2
deflection (+5 Barkskin)(+4 mage armor) (4 shield).
BAB: 8.
Saves: Fort (9=6+1+2), Ref (9=2+5+2), Will (8=6+2).
Attack: Bite+20 (2d6+1d6(shock)+11), 2 Claws+20 (1d8+1d6(shock)+11), 2 Tail 
Slaps+18 (2d6+1d6(shock)+6).
Ability Scores: Str 30=16+4+2+2+4(Naturalist)+2(item), Dex 20=12+4+4(Naturalist), Con 13, Int 7, Wis 10, Cha 11.
Skills:  Acrobatics (Dex) 8 ranks (+4 from tails), Bluff (Cha), Craft (Int), Fly (Dex) 4 ranks, Knowledge (planes) (Int), Perception (Wis) 8 ranks, Sense Motive (Wis) 4 ranks, Stealth (Dex) 8 ranks.
Feats: Improved Natural Attack (Bite), Improved Natural Attack (Claw), Improved Natural Attack (Tail Slap), Power Attack.
Special Abilities
Darkvision (Ex) 
Link (Ex)
Share Spells (Ex)
Evasion (Ex)
Devotion (Ex)
Multiattack
Evolution Pool: 16.5
Evolutions:  Claws [Free], limbs (Arms) [Free], limbs (Legs) [Free], 1EP Improved Natural Armor, Bite, Improved Damage (Bite), Improved Damage (Claw), Improved Damage (Tail Slap), Tail (x2), Tail Slap (x2), Reach (Bite), Reach (Claw), Reach (Claw), Reach (Tail Slap), Reach (Tail Slap), 2EP Ability Increase [Strength]. =16EP
Items:  +1 Shocking Amulet of Mighty Fists: Cost 8,000 gp (+2), +2 Vest of Resistance: Cost 3,000 gp (+2), +2 Gloves of Giant Strength: Cost 3,000 gp (+2) (DM said to go with the +50% cost for different slot for both the vest and gloves), Boots of Speed: Cost 6,000 gp, +2 Ring of Protection: Cost 4,000 gp (+2).
Carrying Capacity
Light   532 lbs. or less
Medium  533-1064 lbs.
Heavy   1065-1600 lbs.

Anything look wrong to anyone?

And sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Ozuma, please avoid updating the question based on information answers provide as that then invalidates the answers. Our format doesn't handle iterative/constantly updated questions, that type of thing may be better suited for a forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The eidolon's Strength and AC are slightly too high.

It's mostly correct, but everything derived from the eidolon's Strength score is slightly off. And if *barkskin* is coming from the 10th level Summoner, then it is also 1 AC too high.

**Parts that are correct:**

Considering the information in your question, it seems you are using the [eidolon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons/) from *Advanced Players Guide* (APG) and not the unchained version of the eidolon.

The eidolon has +8 BAB, 32 skill ranks, and 4 feats. You have that right.

With 13 Con, 20 Dex, 10 Wis, and a +2 resistance bonus to saving throws, it looks like the saving throws are also calculated correctly.

The eidolon would have 14 evolution points, and it looks like you used the half-elf's favored class bonus to give 2.5 more, so you have (technically 16.5 but effectively) 16 points to spend. And counting the evolutions, you have spent 16 points.

**Parts that are incorrect:**

As addressed in [MoshpitWallflower's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/125765/32840), when a 10th level caster uses [*barkskin*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/barkskin/), then it should provide a +4 enhancement bonus to natural armor, rather than +5. This means the AC (and flat-footed AC) are 1 higher than they should be.

You are also using the [Naturalist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/naturalist/)'s ability to enhance the eidolon's strength and dexterity. Since a 10th level Naturalist counts as a 8th level Hunter for determining the effect of their Animal Focus feature, you correctly add the +4 enhancement bonuses to Strength and Dexterity.

These are enhancement bonuses, and will not stack with the Strength enhancement bonus from your item of [giant strength](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-giant-strength/), because bonuses of the same type don't usually stack. It also would not stack with [*bull's strength*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bull-s-strength/) or any other enhancement bonus to Strength.

#### What should the stat block look like?

The feats and features don't change. First let's address the AC. With *barkskin* active, the eidolon should have 33 AC, 17 touch AC, and 28 flat-footed AC. This includes the +5 Dex modifier, +2 deflection, +4 armor bonus from *mage armor*, +4 shield bonus from *shield*, +4 natural armor from eidolon progression, and +4 natural armor enhancement bonus from *barkskin*.

The eidolon's Strength score should be **28**. The base form starts at 16, then add the untyped +4 Str/Dex score bonus from progression, with 2 ability score increases, and another +2 from the Ability Increase evolution. That's 24; your Animal Focus gives a +4 enhancement bonus for a total of 28, which means it has a STR modifier of (28-10)/2 = +9.

With a BAB of +8, a STR modifier of +9, Multiattack, the feats and evolutions you chose, and the +1 from the Amulet of Mighty Fists, your eidolon's melee attacks should be as follows:

- Bite +18 (2d6 + 10)(+1d6 electric)
- 2 claws +18 (1d8 + 10)(+1d6 electric)
- 2 tail slaps +16 (2d6 + 5)(+1d6 electric)

And when using [Power Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final/) with +8 BAB, the eidolon takes a -3 to attack rolls for extra damage, so those numbers should look like:

- Bite +15 (2d6 + 16)(+1d6 electric)
- 2 claws +15 (1d8 + 16)(+1d6 electric)
- 2 tail slaps +13 (2d6 + 8)(+1d6 electric)

The [carrying capacity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity/) is then: 400 lbs for light, 800 lbs for medium, and 1200 lbs for heavy. The eidolon can lift up to 1200 lbs over its head, and push or pull up to 6000 lbs along the ground.

The eidolon's full attacks will hit hard, and the amulet lets it ignore DR/magic. It won't be as effective versus enemies with other types of DR, although that's a common problem for eidolons.

---

**Recommendations instead of using a redundant Strength enhancement item:**

- With 13 Con, this eidolon only has 52 hp (8d10 + 8). An item to enhance its Constitution would make it more survivable.
- The Naturalist's eidolon loses the Shield Ally ability. Maybe spend more to boost the eidolon's saving throws.
- Summoners are full casters, and can replace a fallen eidolon with another monster as a standard action. Leave the eidolon as is, and give the Summoner a useful item instead.

Answer (score 3):

well, for one, if you're a 10th level summoner, and assuming that it's you who's casting the barkskin, shouldn't that only be a +4 bonus (doesn't reach a +5 until 12th level caster)?

Comment: that +5 has the dex next ot it

Comment: i mean, you have it listed as "(+5 Barkskin)"

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's not forbidden to take monster feats on a eidolon, [but it is highly dubious and will definitely make the game little to no fun](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ow7u?Eidolon-taking-monster-feats), especially with those feat choices.

I'm not going to go too deep into the [naturalist template](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/naturalist/), because I'm unsure of what aspects you chose here, but based on that natural AC with only one stack of  Improved Natural Armor seems too high. Also consider that your ring might not stack with other deflection bonuses.

All the same, this seems like it's going to be no fun to play, even if it is correctly balanced. Try adding some fun feats in there!

Also, not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question, maybe try some forums instead?

Comment: DM said i could ether take weapon feats OR upgrade the natural attacks, so i went for the natural attacks cuz honestly it's kinda fearsome and or DM has a tendency of pitting us against things we have no business fighting so i needed as much damage per round as i could get......and i could have went for a sting instead of tail slap but i thought 5 primary attacks was a bit much XD

Comment: and the aspects were bear and tiger (+4 to str and dex)

Comment: What would be fun feats?

Comment: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-evolution/
and 
https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/evolved-summoned-monster/

Answer (score 1):

RAW you can use monster feats with a humanoid, but this is highly discouraged in most settings, for fairly obvious reasons. 
http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ow7u?Eidolon-taking-monster-feats

Comment: I read that thread, and I'm not sure *highly discouraged in most settings, for fairly obvious reasons* is the best summary of it. The *in most settings* seems to be *In 2012 monster feats were banned for PCs in Pathfinder Society* and the *obvious reasons* seem to be *Because they're in the monster book*, which, like, half the folks in that thread say is meaningless. If this answer is to offer an opinion, it should do so boldly rather than implying that the linked thread has the answer.